# Trying to setup my go project on aws with app config. While creating service in my cluster getting below error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

"msg":"error while creating config","error":"error while starting configuration session: operation error AppConfigData: StartConfigurationSession, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , request send failed, Post https://appconfigdata.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/configurationsessions: dial tcp 13.521.118.188:443: i/o

I thought it's due to security group rules, allowed all traffic and gave full permissions to taskdefinition role. Still getting above error.